# Problem getting puppeteer-cluster waiting on page event before closing

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I'm currently setting up a CI environment to automate e2e tests our team runs in a test harness. I am setting this up on Gitlab and currently using Puppeteer. I have an event that fires from our test harness that designates when the test is complete. Now I am trying to "pool" the execution so I don't use up all resources or run out of listeners. I decided to try out "puppeteer-cluster" for this task. I am close to having things working, however I can't seem to get it to wait for the event on page before closing the browser. Prior to using puppeteer-cluster, I was passing in a callback to my function and when the custom event was fired (injected via exposeFunction), I would go about calling it. That callback function is now being passed in data though now and therefore not waiting. I can't seem to find a way to get the execution to wait and was hoping someone might have an idea here.  If anyone has any recommendations, I'd love to hear them.

```
test('Should launch the browser and run e2e tests', async (done) => {
    try {
        const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
            concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
            maxConcurrency: 10,
            monitor: false,
            timeout: 1200000,
            puppeteerOptions: browserConfig
        });
        
        // Print errors to console
        cluster.on("taskerror", (err, data) => {
            console.log(`Error crawling ${data}: ${err.message}`);
        });
        
        //Setup our task to be run
        await cluster.task( async ({page, data: {testUrl, isLastIndex, cb}, worker}) => {
            console.log(`Test starting at url: ${testUrl} - isLastIndex: ${isLastIndex}`);
        
            await page.goto(testUrl);
            await page.waitForSelector('#testHarness');

            await page.exposeFunction('onCustomEvent', async (e) => {         
                if (isLastIndex === true){ ; 
                    //Make a call to our callback, finalizing tests are complete
                    cb();
                }
                console.log(`Completed test at url: ${testUrl}`);
            });
    
            await page.evaluate(() => {
                document.addEventListener('TEST_COMPLETE', (e) => {
                    window.onCustomEvent('TEST_COMPLETE');   
                    console.log("TEST COMPLETE");         
                });
            });
        });

        //Perform the assignment of all of our xml tests to an array
        let arrOfTests = await buildTestArray();
        const arrOfTestsLen = arrOfTests.length;

        for( let i=0; i < arrOfTestsLen; ++i){
            //push our tests on task queue
            await cluster.queue( {testUrl: arrOfTests[i], isLastIndex: (i === arrOfTestsLen - 1), cb: done });
        };

        await cluster.idle();
        await cluster.close();
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR:',error);
        done();
        throw error;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got something working, but it really feels hacky to me and I'm not really sure it is the right approach. So should anyone have the proper way of doing this or a more recommended way, don't hesitate to respond. I am posting here shoudl anyone else deal with something similar.  I was able to get this working with a bool and setInterval. I have pasted working result below.

```
await cluster.task( async ({page, data: {testUrl, isLastIndex, cb}, worker}) => {
            
     let complete = false;

     console.log(`Test starting at url: ${testUrl} - isLastIndex: ${isLastIndex}`);
        
     await page.goto(testUrl)       
     await page.waitForSelector('#testHarness');
     await page.focus('#testHarness');
            
     await page.exposeFunction('onCustomEvent', async (e) => {   
         console.log("Custom event fired");      
         if (isLastIndex === true){ ; 
             //Make a call to our callback, finalizing tests are complete
             cb();
             complete = true;
             //console.log(`VAL IS ${complete}`);
         }
         console.log(`Completed test at url: ${testUrl}`);
                
     });

     //This will run on the actual page itself. So setup an event listener for
     //the TEST_COMPLETE event sent from the test harness itself
     await page.evaluate(() => {
         document.addEventListener('TEST_COMPLETE', (e) => {
             window.onCustomEvent('TEST_COMPLETE');                                       
         });
     });
           
     await new Promise(resolve => {
         try {
             let timerId = setInterval(()=>{
                 if (complete === true){
                     resolve();
                     clearInterval(timerId);
                 }
             }, 1000);
         } catch (e) {
             console.log('ERROR ', e);
         }
                    
     });
});
```